# how do i make my app to take the full size of the web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to make a simple header body footer page witg grid css. I want my header to be at the top of the page, my footer at the bottom of the page and my body to take the space left between them.
When i fill my body with lorem ipsom everything is ok but when there is nothing my body is not taking the space left. And that means the my footer is right after the body and the space after the footer is blank. How can u resolve that ?

[image]

Here are the file of all my project:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Vite + React</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
</body>
```

style.css

```
html, body {
min-height: 100vh;
min-width: 100vw;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
</React.StrictMode>,
)
```

index.css

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
min-width: 100vw;
min-height: 100vh;
}
```

App.jsx

```
import './App.css'

function App() {

return (
  <div className='app'>
    <div className='header'>Header</div>
    <div className='body'>lorem100</div>
    <div className='footer'>Footer</div>
  </div>
 )
}

export default App
```

App.css

```
.app {
 display: grid;
 min-height: 100%;
 grid-template-rows: 100px auto 100px;
```

}

```
.header {
  background-color: aqua;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.body {
  background-color: rgb(1, 12, 12);
  color: aliceblue;
}

.footer {
  background-color: rgb(235, 181, 4);
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you just posted the fully rendered HTML and the CSS that goes with it.

Comment: @ralph.m where can i find that ? in my project directory ?

Comment: @fathi93 from browser page source :D

Comment: Yes, as @KiranShahi said, the rendered code is what gets displayed in the browser, and you can grab it by viewing the page source (kind of like opening the hood of a car). (On a Mac just hit option + command + u.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know my answer will help you. But, it is hard to set header & footer first and body to be left because **Stacking Order Context** works from top to bottom, left to right.

So, this code could be helpful.

```
<div className="container">
  <div className="header"></div>
  <div className="footer"></div>
</div>
```

This is css

```
.app > .container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: aqua;
  padding: 100px 0px;
}

.app > .container > .header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
}

.app > .container > .footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the following class to have the desired effect:

```
.app {
    display: grid;
    min-height: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 100px auto 100px;
    height:100vh;
   }
```

This will make the page have the height of entire visible area. And considering you have have given "auto" sizing to middle grid item in your grid template, the body will be expanded between the header and footer(which will be at bottom now).

Answer (score 0):

You need also a

```css
grid-template-columns: auto;
```

Comment: i did it but nothing changes

Comment: You dont need any of the other (min-)hight properties. Remove them and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the body height as
height : 100%

Answer (score 0):

You need also to set `height: 100vh` at your `app` css class.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-engelbart-5zkfkx?file=/src/styles.css)

Answer (score 0):

`display: grid;` is mainly for 2d layouts (horizontal **AND** vertical), while `display: flex;` is used mostly for 1d layouts (horizontal **OR** vertical). You have a vertical layout and though not necessary, I'd advice you use flexbox, and I'll show you  how you can implement what you want to do with flexbox.

App.jsx (just the HTML)

```
  <div className='app'>
    <div className='header'>Header</div>
    <div className='body'>lorem100</div>
    <div className='footer'>Footer</div>
  </div>
```

App.css

```
.app {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app > header {
  height: 100px
  background-color: aqua;
}

.app > body {
  flex: 1; /* Fills up extra space (every other thing after others have taken their respective heights) */
  background-color: rgb(1, 12, 12);
  color: aliceblue;
}

.app > footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(235, 181, 4);
}
```

Remember, you don't have to use flex over grid, as grid can also handle 1 dimensional layouts, I just feel flexbox is more straightforward for these type of formats.

Let me know if it works out or if there's more help you need on it :)